# How do I solve "couldn't be bound error" in SQL Server in my criteria?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, rdbms

I have a table called `Transfer`. When I try to perform `LEFT JOIN` it's not detecting that table from database.

Here is my query:

```
Select
    tmp.ID,
    tmp.Name,
    st.Store,
    Number
FROM
    #tmpStore tmp
LEFT JOIN #store st on st.ID = tmp.ID
LEFT JOIN Transfer tr on tr.number = st.number  --Here is error
```

**ERROR**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transfer'.

When I move the mouse on tr.number, it throws

> The multi part identifier `tr.number` couldn't be bound

Only this particular table is showing an error while doing LEFT JOIN. When I do join with another table, it's not showing an error.

Comment: Do you have a table named `Transfer`? Use `[Transfer]`

Comment: Can you select directly from `Transfer`?

Comment: @ollie no I cannot retrieve directly when I try `select top 1 * from transfer`, but when try right click and select top 1000, it's retrieving. why?

Comment: @Sami I tried your way also. I cannot. only for that table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Transfer` is a reserved word used in `ALTER SCHEMA`, so you can execute your query like below:

```
Select
    tmp.ID,
    tmp.Name,
    st.Store,
    Number
FROM
    #tmpStore tmp
LEFT JOIN #store st on st.ID = tmp.ID
LEFT JOIN DBName.Schema.[Transfer] tr on tr.number = st.number;
```

For more information see: *[ALTER SCHEMA (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)*